# Bespoke.js themes in documentation and demo are different

Tags: javascript, html, presentation, bespoke.js

I found amazing html5 framework for presentation. 
Documentation: https://github.com/bespokejs/bespoke 
Demo: [http://markdalgleish.com/projects/bespoke.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/bespoke.js/)

But I was surprised that carousel theme is absent. 
Is there way to use themes as in demo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the themes are not publicly available on npm you would have to create the theme on your own. I was also wondering though why most of the themes of the demo page are not available as packages already.

Since you asked specifically for the carousel theme I recreated and published it on npm. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bespoke-theme-carousel). To integrate themes simply follow the way described in the [docs](https://github.com/bespokejs/bespoke#using-themes). You can find a list of all themes on npm under the [keyword bespoke-theme](https://www.npmjs.org/browse/keyword/bespoke-theme).

If you have any kind of improvements for the theme feel free to open an issue or make a pull request on github ([bespoke-theme-carousel repo](https://github.com/frncsdrk/bespoke-theme-carousel)).